# Time dilation due to gravity

Tags: spacetime, time-dilation, gravitational-redshift

I'm getting conflicting statements when it comes to time dilation due to gravity. Some sites say time slows down near the source of gravity and some say it's faster. Can anyone she'd some light on this?

Comment: Can you give an example of a site that says that gravity causes time to speed up? I have never seen anyone make that claim, only the opposite.

Comment: According to Stephen Hawking, time slows down in a black hole.

Comment: Yes, and that is consistent with the claim that time slows down in a strong gravitational field. But where did you find the opposite claim?